# VBA for creating multiple PDFs

Tags: vba

Have a format for billing for partner ( no of partner 176 ) and want to create multiple PDF with different partner name (Partner names are mentioned in partnernamesheet from A1 to A176). I have created a loop however the loop which help me create the different PDF however unable to apply the name range from different sheet while saving PDFs.

```
Sub creatingloopforprint() 
  i = 1 
  Do While i < 5 
    Worksheets("Invoice format").Activate Range("M14").Value = i 
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True 
    i = i + 1 
  Loop 
End Sub
```

Comment: This is the code i have written for creating loop for different sheet

Comment: Please dont put your code in a comment - just edit your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

This will save the excel as a PDF using the `"A" & I` naming logic.

```
Sub creatingloopforprint()
    Dim i As Integer

    i = 1

    For i = 1 To 176:
        Worksheets("Invoice format").Activate Range("M14").Value = i
        ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="A" & i

    Next i

End Sub
```

From here the specific saved and prints can be updated as necessary.